# rpm spec file is not executed on rpm install

Tags: installation, rpm, web-applications

I am creating an rpm installer for my web applications.
On the spec file, i got this on %prep and %install

```
%prep
#will create and cd to the named directory before doing the untar. 
%setup  -c -n %{name}

%install
php install.php
```

The issue is that when execute the command `sudo rpmbuild -ba webapp.spec`, the install.php file is executed. It executes the code to update the source, database and fix scripts. But nothing was executed when I install the rpm file like this command `sudo rpm -i webapp-1.0-0.i386.rpm`

I'm wondering if rpm will only execute the spec file when building/packaging the rpm but not on the rpm installation. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need `%post` http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html#S2-RPM-INSIDE-ERASE-TIME-SCRIPTS

Comment: And learn the difference between build-time and install-time scripts.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, thanks. I should add it on %post. now i'm getting error: Failed dependencies:
 /bin/sh is needed